# .NET Function Framework with Google Cloud Functions with multiple functions in 1 project

Tags: .net, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a .NET Function Framework project to deploy to Google Cloud Functions. I've successfully created a single HTTP function and deployed it, but was hoping you could group several functions into 1 project and deploy them as a unit (each function responding on a different address).

Is this possible and if so how do you do it?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: As per this [isuue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/77998087). Only `cloud functions for firebase` supports this but not `GCP functions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/77998087), Only `Firebase Functions` supports deploying functions as a unit.
You can [organize multiple functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions#organize_functions_in_codebases) in `firebase.json`. If you want to use `GCP functions` you can follow the [workaround](https://medium.com/google-cloud/express-routing-with-google-cloud-functions-36fb55885c68) mentioned in the medium